# how to continue a foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I have the for each loop below and would like to know how i would be able to continue this after an exception has been thrown so that it goes onto the next next array index, and the system doesn't fail.

```
try
{
//making name array and other checks 
    foreach (string s in namearry)
    {
        var timelineData = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetMyTimeline(s);
        TwitterData.TimeLineData(timelineData, s, int.Parse(dr["ClientId"].ToString()));
        //  var followersId = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetFolowersId(s);
        // var loc = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetFolowersLoc(followersId);
        //  TwitterData.Follower(loc, s);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //logging exception 
}
```

Comment: put your try/catch within the foreach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally i would try to avoid all the exceptions. In your case you can handle the exception within the foreach loop. In the following examples i have added the necessary checks to avoid exception occuring in first place. like this

```
foreach (string s in namearry)
{
    try
    {
        var timelineData = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetMyTimeline(s);
        if(timelineData!=null)
        {
             int clientID;
             if(int.TryParse(dr["ClientId"].ToString(), out clientID))
             {
                  TwitterData.TimeLineData(timelineData, s, clientID);            
             }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        //do logging here.
    }
}
```

Comment: so by putting the try and catch in the for each will stop the program from breaking, in that case would i still need the one which i have

Comment: if you are doing anything else in your function then you need it else no need of it.

Comment: if i leave the other try and catch it still would jump out of the loop or not

Comment: I am pulling data for the row from another database.

Comment: because this loop in inside of another

Comment: inner try catch will handle the exception that will occur within the loop. Any exception that happens outside the loop will be handled by the outer try catch.

Comment: +1 for defensively coding rather than relying on the handling

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, you broke out with an exception, instead move the try/catch inside the loop.

```
foreach (string s in namearry)
{
    try {
        //making name array and other checks 
        var timelineData = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetMyTimeline(s);
        TwitterData.TimeLineData(timelineData, s, int.Parse(dr["ClientId"].ToString()));
        //  var followersId = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetFolowersId(s);
        // var loc = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetFolowersLoc(followersId);
        //  TwitterData.Follower(loc, s);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        //logging exception 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your **try-catch** statement into the loop and use **continue** key word in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `try` *inside* the foreach, rather than outside.
Or, if you need it outside, put another one inside, that handles exceptions.

```
try{
//making name array and other checks, that may trigger exceptions
    foreach (string s in namearry)
    {
        try
        {
            var timelineData = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetMyTimeline(s);
            TwitterData.TimeLineData(timelineData, s, int.Parse(dr["ClientId"].ToString()));
            //  var followersId = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetFolowersId(s);
            // var loc = oAuthTwitterWrapper.GetFolowersLoc(followersId);
            //  TwitterData.Follower(loc, s);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //logging exception: this will override the outer handler, which will not be called.
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex){
    //logging exception
    //exceptions raised before entering the foreach are handled here
}
```